# Creating an Instance in Weka is very slow

Tags: java, weka

I'm using [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/) to train a classifier. However, the problem is that my feature space is quite large and creating an `Instance` with Weka is REALLY slow. I think my code is doing it inefficiently and probably there is a better way to do it with Weka.

Here is a code sample of a test case (try to run it and see how slow):

```
        int numb_features = 20000;
        FastVector features = new FastVector(numb_features + 1);
        List<String> plainFeatures = new ArrayList<String>();
        for ( Integer i = 0; i < numb_features; i++ ) {
            features.addElement( new Attribute(i.toString()) );
            plainFeatures.add(i.toString());
        }
        Instances data = new Instances("", features, 100);
        int number_of_samples = 10;

        for ( int i = 0; i < number_of_samples; i++ ) {
            System.out.println( "Adding a sample!" );
            Instance instance = new Instance( numb_features );
            Attribute att;

            for ( String feature : plainFeatures ) {
                att = data.attribute(feature);
                instance.setValue(att, 0);
            }
            Instance sparseInstance = new SparseInstance(instance);
            sparseInstance.setDataset(data);
        }
```

My question:

What's wrong with my usage of Weka that is making creating an instance slow? And how to improve it?